# Wordpress multilanguage URL

Tags: wordpress, url, plugins, multilingual, taxonomy

I'm building **my own theme in WordPress**, and the website will be in multiple languages.

All I need is to find a way to **assign a language to each page**, and this language should be **added to the URL as well**. (I'm guessing adding a taxonomy, but I'm not sure how to add this to the URL)

I will create a different template page per individual page. Most plugins try to translate each page, this I don't need.

Lastly, of course, I will create a separate **menu per language**, but these links should link to the correct page URL (with the ../language/..)?

Is there a way/ plugin that can help me do this?

Thanks a lot to all who can help me with this!

Comment: I have had good success with [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) in the past, which provides everything you're looking for. Polylang has free and paid versions. [WPML](https://wpml.org/) is also a popular one, but I have not used it extensively

Comment: Ahh, Polylang indeed does everything that I was looking for, way better than the other plugins I got recommended. Thanks for pointing me toward it!